# How can I add a custom property to a RadioButtonList items?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, radiobuttonlist

How can I add a bound [Html5 data- attribute](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) to the items generated with a bound `RadioButtonList`?

My code looks like this:

```
<asp:Repeater Id="QuestionList" ...>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:RadioButtonList DataSource='<%# Eval("Answers") %>'
                         SelectedValue='<%# Eval("SelectedAnswerId") %>'
                         DataTextField="Answer" 
                         DataValueField="AnswerId"
                         Tag='<%# Eval("QuestionId") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

```cs
var List<Question> questions = GetQuestions();
QuestionList.DataSource = questions;
QuestionList.DataBind();
```

It is bound to a class structure that looks like this:

```
public class Question
{
    int QuestionId;
    string Question;
    List<Answer> Answers;
}

public class Answers
{
    int AnswerId;
    string Answer;
    bool SomeFlag;
}
```

I need to add `SomeFlag` to the UI for jQuery to use, so the end result is that each item generated should look like this:

```
<input type="radio" data-flag="true" ... />
```

Is there a way to add a html data- attribute to the input objects generated from a bound `RadioButtonList`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an Attribute in the ItemDataBound event of Repeater, try something like:

```
protected void repeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    // if it is an item (not header or footer)
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        // get your radioButtonList
        RadioButtonList optionsList = (RadioButtonList)e.Item.FindControl("rblOptionsList");

        // loop in options of the RadioButtonList
        foreach (ListItem option in optionsList.Items)
        {
            // add a custom attribute
            option.Attributes["data-flag"] = "true";
        }
    }
}
```

And remember to set the IDs and Events for your controls

```
<asp:Repeater Id="QuestionList" ItemDataBound="QuestionList_ItemDataBound" ...>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblOptionsList" DataSource='<%# Eval("Answers") %>'
                         SelectedValue='<%# Eval("SelectedAnswerId") %>'
                         DataTextField="Answer" 
                         DataValueField="AnswerId"
                         Tag='<%# Eval("QuestionId") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: That's very interesting.  I remember trying years ago to add attributes to a `ListItem` and having them not be rendered.  I guess things have changed since the last time I tried that!

Comment: This works, however it applies the attribute to the `<span>` tag that surrounds the `<input>` and `<label>`. That's fine with me though, thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use ListItem attributes to add custom attributes to the items in the radio button list. You can check how your html is generated for radio button list and make jquery to get the required data attribute for you.

*On server side*

```
ListItem li1 = new ListItem();
ListItem li2 = new ListItem();
li1.Attributes.Add("data-flag", "true");
li2.Attributes.Add("data-flag", "true");
RadioButtonList1.Items.Add(li1);
RadioButtonList1.Items.Add(li2);
```

*Generated html for radio button list*

```
<table id="RadioButtonList1" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td><span data-flag="true"><input id="RadioButtonList1_0" type="radio" name="RadioButtonList1" value="" /></span></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><span data-flag="true"><input id="RadioButtonList1_1" type="radio" name="RadioButtonList1" value="" /></span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

*Accessing in jquery*

```
$(':radio[id*=RadioButtonList1]').click(function(){
      alert($(this).closest('span').data('flag'));
})
```

Comment: Interesting, that didn't used to work.  I guess I haven't tried that in several versions!

Comment: +1 for pointing out how to access it from jQuery :) It took me a minute to notice the attribute got added to the span tag, not the input tag

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet if you need to generate the attributes server-side would be to subclass the `RadioButtonList` control and override the `Render` method.

If you have a copy of Reflector or a similar product that can show decompiled code, this would be very helpful in determining exactly where the `ListItem` element is being rendered as a radio button.

Comment: I don't have Reflector. Do you know if the default code for the `RadioButtonList.Render` method is anywhere online?

Comment: @Rachel  I'm afraid I don't know.  I believe there is at least one other tool that works the way Reflector does, but I don't know its name off-hand.  Sorry. :(

Comment: Well +1 anyways because it is still a viable solution that is probably the best for more complex templates :)

Comment: 9 years too late, but https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/UI/WebControls/RadioButtonList.cs